# Orientability and unit tangent bundle of surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, orientation

What can we say about the orientability of the unit tangent bundle $ UTM $ of $ M $?

The unit tangent bundle of the sphere $ S^2 $ is $ \mathbb{R}P^3 $ see [A question on the unit tangent bundle of the sphere and $SO(3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850610/a-question-on-the-unit-tangent-bundle-of-the-sphere-and-so3)

The unit tangent bundle of $ T^2 $ is $ T^3 $ (torus is Lie group so parallelizable so unit tangent bundle is trivial)

The unit tangent bundle of an orientable surface $ \Sigma_g $ of genus $ g \geq 2 $ is
$$
UT(\Sigma_g) \cong SL_2(\mathbb{R})/\pi_1(\Sigma_g)
$$

For the non orientable surfaces the story is similar. Every unit tangent bundle is double covered by the unit tangent bundle of its orientable double cover.

For example the unit tangent bundle of the projective plane is the homogeneous (q=1) lens space with fundamental group $ C_4 $ cyclic of order 4.
$$
UT(\mathbb{R}P^2) \cong L_{4,1} \cong SU_2/C_4
$$
So in particular $ UT(\mathbb{R}P^2) $ is orientable. See
https://www.projecteuclid.org/journals/nihonkai-mathematical-journal/volume-13/issue-1/Unit-Tangent-Bundle-over-Two-Dimensional-Real-Projective-Space/nihmj/1273779621.full

On the other hand, the unit tangent bundle of the Klein bottle is this 3 manifold double covered by the torus

[Unit (co)tangent bundle of Klein bottle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436113/unit-cotangent-bundle-of-klein-bottle)

Is the unit tangent bundle always orientable?

edit: [Orientability of the total space of a vector bundle and total space of its sphere bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171567/orientability-of-the-total-space-of-a-vector-bundle-and-total-space-of-its-spher)

Comment: Hint: Start [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129514/why-is-the-tangent-bundle-orientable).

Comment: Once you got orientability of $TM$, construct a nonvanishing vector field on $TM$ normal to $UTM$.

Comment: More generally, the sphere bundle of $E \to M$ is orientable if $w_1(E) = w_1(TM)$. If $\operatorname{rank} E > 1$, the converse is also true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The total space $TM$ of tangent bundle to any manifold $M$ (orientable or not) is orientable, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129514/why-is-the-tangent-bundle-orientable).
2. The total space $UTM$ of the unit tangent bundle is a hypersurface in $TM$ which admits a nowehere vanishing normal vector field (at each point $(x,v)\in UTM$ take the normal vector  $((x,v),v)$).
3. Thus, $UTM$ is a cooriented hypersurface in an orientable manifold, hence, is itself orientable.